# Using Indefinite Article

Tags: articles, ellipsis, indefinite-article

Is it not necessary to use the indefinite article ***an*** before ***e-mail*** in the following sentence?

> " ... Six months later you find a name and e-mail address on a card or an old piece of paper."

It's clear why a second ***on*** has been left out before ***an old piece of paper***, but since *a/an* are used in different ways, I can't understand why it has been omitted there.

Comment: Interestingly, the writer didn't omit *an* in *on a card or an old piece of paper*. It'd be absolutely fine for me.

Comment: @Damkerng T: Repeating the article, "... *a* card or *an* old piece of paper" subtly reinforces the idea that one will have to search through a *variety* of old scraps when looking for something that was scribbled down.

Comment: @TRomano: That's a really interesting point! But do you have any idea why the first "an" has been omitted? Is it "just a style issue", according to Teacher KSHuang?

Comment: Because "a name and email address" is understood to be a "contact info unit", as it were, they are "of a piece".   Cf. "Can you send me *the name and address*?".

Comment: @ TRomano: Thanks a world! It's a really useful tip.

Comment: @TRomano I would almost like to change my answer to match your second comment :D.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I would have liked to leave this as a comment instead, but my rep isn't high enough yet.

Personally, I think it's just a style issue. No actual grammar rules have been broken. Having "an" would make things more clear, but they are not unclear without the "an."

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a grammar page regarding this issue exactly, but if it helps, you're not alone in asking questions about dropping indefinite articles:

http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/omitting-indefinite-articles-in-the-title.2964148/

And I totally agree with Damkerng's comment in the original post. I had found it interesting as well that the original speaker of the sentence had omitted the article in the first part and not the second.